# Why install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package x86 to use SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-c++

I wrote windows application with C# and SQLite. When Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package x86 was installed on a PC application runs correctly but if Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package x86 not install, application doesn't run. Why?
Is SQLite depend on Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package x86 ?

Answer (score 5):

The version of SQLite is compiled by VS2010, and it depends on the C runtime libaries, thus it needs Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package x86.

Comment: **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package x86** install with .Net version 4 ?

Comment: I don'know that. But i think .NET package won't include C runtime libraries

Comment: Yes, .NET does NOT contain the C++ redistributable package.  It is a different thing altogether.  The .NET Framework compiles code written in .NET.  The C++ redistributable is a "runtime", which means it takes compiled code and runs it - just like Java has the JRE.  C++ code came before .NET code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. SQLite is probably written in C++. It's compiled with /MD option which means it needs the msvcrt#.dlls at runtime. The Restributable Package installs this without which it cannot run

Comment: Is that to say that not specifying /MD means that the library doesn't need the msvcrt#.dll(s)? From the documentation, it seems that all the available values all use the runtime library in some fashion. Could you clarify?

Comment: If a C or C++ program is compiled in the microsoft compilers with /MT instead of /MD, then they don't need the runtimes because they use the static libraries which are compiled into the code.

Answer (score 1):

Because SQLite obviously developed the SQLite.Interop.dll in C++, and because they say so:

> **(11) Why do I get a DllNotFoundException (for "sqlite3.dll" or "SQLite.Interop.dll") when trying to run my application?** 
>
> Either the named dynamic link library (DLL) cannot be located or it cannot be loaded due to missing dependencies. Make sure the named dynamic link library is located in the application directory or a directory along the system PATH and try again. **Also, be sure the necessary Visual C++ runtime redistributable has been installed unless you are using a dynamic link library that was built statically linked to it.**

Emphasis mine on that last part.  You need the static binaries from the [system.data.sqlite download page](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) in order to NOT need the C++ runtime.  On that same page, where the binaries are provided, those that do require it will tell you it is - for example, the Visual C++ 2010 SP1 runtime for x64 is required for 4.0, and Update 4 of that is needed for .NET 4.5, according to the page.  I've used the 2015 version, Update 3, with the .NET 4.0 versions with no issues.

Note - you might not be aware, but if you try hosting an application that uses the SQLite DLLs on a file share and connect to that application across the network from a workstation, that workstation will still need the C++ runtime because it is running the application in its memory.

**Reference:** http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q11

Link to **Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3**, which I know works with the 64-bit, .NET 4.0 versions of the SQLite binaries:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840

Answer (score 0):

SQLite depends on the Visual C++ runtime, but you **don't** need to install it on the client machine. The [system.data.sqlite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) download page contains several "static" packages that already contain the runtime.

> All the "static" packages contain either native or mixed-mode assembly binaries linked statically to the appropriate version of the Visual C++ runtime. Typically, these packages are used in cases where customer machines may not have the necessary version of the Visual C++ runtime installed and it cannot be installed due to limited privileges.

For example, on my machine I am running Windows 8.1 x64 so I went under **Precompiled Statically-Linked Binaries for 64-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.0)** and downloaded **sqlite-netFx40-static-binary-x64-2010-1.0.90.0.zip**.

> This binary package contains all the binaries for the x64 version of the System.Data.SQLite 1.0.90.0 (3.8.2) package. The Visual C++ 2010 SP1 runtime for x64 is statically linked. The .NET Framework 4.0 is required.

I then unzipped the package and ran **test.exe** to make sure everything works. Zero installation required.

Comment: The problem is you do have to make sure to download the right package.  It is difficult to know which package/DLL you have, if you just get it from a fellow developer or a file share your company uses, until you try to run the application you are using that references it.  For the SQLite.Interop.dll assembly I had, it was required - without the C++ redistributable, it gave me errors the assembly couldn't be found.  After installing it, error went away and it worked fine.